# Learning KML, but finding inconsistencies in specs

Tags: kml

I need to dive into KML, so I'm looking at specs and examples on the web, but I get some inconsistent information.
For instance, some sites say you write things like `<tessellate>true</tessellate>` while others have `<tessellate>1</tessellate>`, and yet others say tessellate isn't necessary any more, since altitudeMode provides the same information.

So I've got a lot of little questions, such as which is safer here, 1/0 or true/false. And what is KML the abbreviation of, Keyhole Markup Language or Keyhole Modelling Language?
But my question basically is, where do I find the standard, the authoritative and definitive reference for KML? Then I can ignore the other sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html
Should probably be considered the primary reference. That's the one I always refer to.

It include Google specific extensions (prefixed by gx:) which you can choose to ignore (or not).

Although 
http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/kml/
is the real definitive source, its nowhere near as accessible as the Google one (which preceded OGC taking on KML) - I dont even know how to read the OGC one!

KML used to represent "Keyhole Markup Language"

Boolean, is probably best considered 1/0 - some clients might understand true etc, but for maximum compatiblity go with 1/0

btw, tessellate is useful in itself, it does not do the same as altitudeMode. They complement each other.

Comment: Thanks. Well, the examples in the OGC site show true/false and the Google ones have 1/0, but I think I'll stick to 1/0.